# null pointer exception when i use radio button

Tags: android

I want to use a `RadioButton` in group button and all that in `dialog` frame but when i want to get text from my `RadioButton`, i get a `NullPointerException`.

there is my layout xml file:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.prompt_permission, null);

                        final RadioGroup radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) promptView.findViewById(R.id.droit);

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                        // set prompts.xml to be the layout file of the alertdialog builder
                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

                        final EditText input = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.editTextMailUserInput);


                        // setup a dialog window
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                   
                                                //input.setText(input.getText());

                                                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                                                RadioButton radioSexButton =(RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                                                 System.out.println(radioSexButton.getText());  
                                            }
                                        })
                                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                        // create an alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        alertD.show();`
```

this is my logCat error :

```
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at com.example.poc_cubbyhole.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:190)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-08 16:10:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(3645):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post LogCat error trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                   
    //input.setText(input.getText());

    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

   // change this part like this
     RadioButton radioSexButton =(RadioButton) promptView.findViewById(selectedId);

    System.out.println(radioSexButton.getText());  
}
```

Comment: you're right that's resolve my problem, thank you :D